# How to Activate HTML Webcam without using GetUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I'm trying to activate the user camera using `HTML`. All of the tutorials I've come across require `GetUserMedia()`, but it's deprecated and disabled on modern versions of Google Chrome. Is there a way to use the webcam on an `HTML` page without `GetUserMedia()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. The `navigator.getUserMedia()` has been deprecated. You have to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` instead for this :)

Here's the MDN link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Hope that works for you ^_^

Comment: A note about the new syntax could be a plus for this correct answer.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to use it without `navigator`?
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319924/access-camera-or-webcam-without-webrtc

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding `GetUserMedia()` is still valid; however, it just has its limitations due to browser specifications.

The following should assist with compatibility/vendor prefixes and such:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                            navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```