# Access camera or webcam without webRTC

Tags: javascript, html, webview, webrtc

In my website, it needs to access camera or webcam. But webRTC is not supported yet on ios webview based on https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88052 (please cmiiw). So, I'm trying to find a way to access it without webRTC. Is there any?

1. And is this following code, a part of utilizing webRTC? Because the console.log shows up on ios webview

   ```
   function hasGetUserMedia() {
     return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || 
       navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
   }

   //then, somewhere in the code
   if (!hasGetUserMedia()) {           
     console.log( "webRTC is not supported in your browser" );//it shows up on ios webview              
   }

   //other code
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false, //no audio
    video: {deviceId: {exact: videoSource.camera_id} }
   })
   ```
2. If yes, so what's the workaround which not using webRTC, and can be run on android webview, ios webview, and web browsers?

Comment: The code listed above is not part of webRTC. You can very well use that with webview.

Comment: I have edited the code, are you sure it's not? Because the console.log shows up.
And the camera device is not accessed

Comment: iOS WebViews don’t support `getUserMedia`. WebRTC is pretty irrelevant to that. So, no, the one method to access webcam streams does not exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 2021 Edit:

We now have access to `getUserMedia` on iOS WebViews!

---

#### The Good News:

As of iOS 14.3, iOS now allows access to `getUserMedia` in a `WKWebView`

Whenever I have questions about browser features like this, I find it very helpful to check out [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=stream). In this case, there is a note on the entry for Safari & Chrome for iOS

> Before iOS 14.3 `getUserMedia` returned no video input devices in `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`, but only directly in Safari

#### The Old News:

Prior to 2021, we could not access `getUserMedia` on iOS outside of Safari. So back then, a workaround was to build a website and direct iOS users to visit the site in Safari instead of making a native app for iOS.

#### The Other News:

`getUserMedia` controls access to a user's camera and microphone, whereas WebRTC helps you *send* that audio/video to another client, like in a video chat. Here you're stuck on getting the video in the first place so you don't need to worry about WebRTC yet, but when you do, I recommend you check out [This article](https://webrtchacks.com/guide-to-safari-webrtc/) that helped me.

And if you want to test `getUserMedia` or WebRTC functions yourself, try using [These provided samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/), so that you can be sure that it is not the fault of your own code :)